# Prove that the graph is a valid tree in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x, tree, graph

I recently solved [this leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/graph-valid-tree/):

> Given n nodes labeled from 0 to n - 1 and a list of undirected edges
>   (each edge is a pair of nodes), write a function to check whether
>   these edges make up a valid tree.
>
> ```
> For example:
>
> Given n = 5 and edges = [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 4]], return true.
>
> Given n = 5 and edges = [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 3], [1, 4]], return false.
> ```
>
> Note: you can assume that no duplicate edges will appear in edges.
>   Since all edges are undirected, [0, 1] is the same as [1, 0] and thus
>   will not appear together in edges.

My code is correct, and runtime beats 80% of answers submitted, but the overall structure is not at all user friendly. Could anyone give some code review to improve readability?

Don't worry what alternative method or improving the solution since it is already in \$O(n)\$.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

class Solution(object):
    def validTree(self, n, edges):
        """
        :type n: int
        :type edges: List[List[int]]
        :rtype: bool
        """
        if not edges:
            if n == 1:
                return True
            elif n == 2:
                return False

        visited_nodes = defaultdict(list)
        count = True
        unvisited = []
        for key, value in edges:

            if key in visited_nodes and value in visited_nodes:
                return False

            if count:
                visited_nodes[key] = []
                visited_nodes[value] = []
                count = False
                continue
            if key in visited_nodes:
                visited_nodes[key].append(value)
                visited_nodes[value] = []
            elif value in visited_nodes:
                visited_nodes[value].append(key)
                visited_nodes[key] = []
            else:
                unvisited.append([key, value])

        for key, value in unvisited:

            if key in visited_nodes and value in visited_nodes:
                return False

            if key in visited_nodes:
                visited_nodes[key].append(value)
                visited_nodes[value] = []
            elif value in visited_nodes:
                visited_nodes[value].append(key)
                visited_nodes[key] = []
            else:
                return False

        return n == len(visited_nodes.keys())

print Solution().validTree(4, [[0, 1], [2, 3], [1, 2]])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before going in depth of your algorithm, a few stylistics notes:

- I assume that the `class Solution(object)` thing is required by leetcode, so it might not apply. But as a general note, your `validTree` method does not need to store/interact with any state. Thus there is no need for it to be a method and would benefit to be defined as a function. Also the naming should be *snake_case* as per PEP8: `def valid_tree(n, edges):`. `is_valid_tree` might also be a better name.
- In Python 2, the `keys` method of dictionaries build and return a new list. It is generally recommended that your use `iterkeys` instead which return a proxy object to the actual keys of the dictionary. However, such object does not support the `len` protocol. But the dictionary support it without having to build anything new: `len(visited_nodes)`.

## Tidy up your special case

Your algorithm performs two checks:

- Every node is reached through an edge;
- Every node can reach each other through at most one path.

The only special case to that is, for only one node, to have no edges. The other cases will be handled by the `for` loops (which will do nothing if `edges` is empty) and the last check. Thus I would write:

```
def is_valid_tree(n, edges):
    if n == 1:
        # 1 node must not have edges
        return not edges
    ...
```

You can also remove all special cases by using default values in `visited_nodes`. More on that later.

## Don't use stuff that you don't use

Sounds weird, doesn't it? But the same goes for your use of `defaultdict`: you use it without using the extra functionalities over `dict`. In fact, using `visited_nodes = {}` will not change anything in your program. So use that instead, it will remove a bit of overhead.

`defaultdict`s usage is to make use of default values instead of having to explicitly assign them, such as in:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
d['test'].append('something')
d['test'].append('something else')
d['other test'].append('a third thing')
print(d) # defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'test': ['something', 'something else'], 'other test': ['a third thing']})
```

But instead, here you explicitly assign empty lists before assigning to them. This is because you explicitly want to define the key of the dictionary; and, in fact, you do not care about the value. Since you do not use values, why using a dictionary to start with? Use a `set` they are like dictionaries, but only for keys:

```
def is_valid_tree(n, edges):
    if n == 1:
        return not edges

    visited_nodes = set()
    count = True
    unvisited = []

    for key, value in edges:
        if key in visited_nodes and value in visited_nodes:
            return False

        if count:
            visited_nodes.add(key)
            visited_nodes.add(value)
            count = False
            continue
        if key in visited_nodes:
            visited_nodes.add(value)
        elif value in visited_nodes:
            visited_nodes.add(key)
        else:
            unvisited.append([key, value])

    for key, value in unvisited:
        if key in visited_nodes and value in visited_nodes:
            return False

        if key in visited_nodes:
            visited_nodes.add(value)
        elif value in visited_nodes:
            visited_nodes.add(key)
        else:
            return False

    return n == len(visited_nodes)
```

## Remove "duplicated" checks

First of, the `count` variable is useless: it only store whether the dictionary (or the set) is empty. You can get the exact same information using `not visited_nodes` which is `True` when `visited_node` is empty and `False` otherwise.

Second, you want to add both `key` and `value` as key (so maybe they need to be renamed) of `visited_nodes` if either of them is already one. You can thus simplify the writing using a boolean `or` and retain the same functionality:

```
if key in visited_nodes or value in visited_nodes:
    visited_nodes.add(key)
    visited_nodes.add(value)
```

Using the `set` approach also help you write less verbose code: use the intersection `&` operator of sets:

```
for edge in edges:
    edge = set(edge)
    commons = visited_nodes & edge

    # If a path exist between the nodes in edge
    if commons == edge:
        # A cycle exist and thus it is not a tree
        return False

    # If a node has been visited or if it is the first edge
    if commons or not visited_nodes:
        # Add the path
        visited_nodes.update(edge)
    else:
        # Process later
        unvisited.append(edge)
```

Third, as stated earlier, you can get rid of all your special cases by initializing `visited_nodes = {0}`. This will allow you to remove the first check (`if n == 1`) since it is now handled by `return n == len(visited_nodes)`. And it will also handle adding branches from the node `0` instead of any two first nodes.

Last, the body of both `for` loops is pretty similar. You may want to factorize it out. Unfortunately, I'm not able to come up with something elegant. It is possible to retry edges by appending them again at the end of `edges` instead of using `unvisited`, like so:

```
def is_valid_tree(n, edges):
    visited_nodes = {0}

    for edge in edges:
        branch = set(edge)
        commons = visited_nodes & branch

        # If a path exist between the nodes in edge
        if commons == branch:
            # A cycle exist and thus it is not a tree
            return False

        # If a node has been visited already
        if commons:
            # Add the branch
            visited_nodes.update(branch)
        else:
            # Process later
            edges.append(edge)

    return n == len(visited_nodes)
```

Unfortunately this can lead to infinite loops in cases where your code would have reached that `return False` in the second `for` loop. However, we can come up with some checks to prevent that. And it's still better than your solution because…

## It appears that you have a bug

Calling `Solution().validTree(5, [[0, 1], [3, 4], [2, 3], [1, 2]])` returns `False`. This is because you delay checking for `[[3, 4], [2, 3]]` but, when running the second checks, instead of delaying `[3, 4]` which would be integrated in a third pass, you `return False`. Same would be true for inputs such as `Solution().validTree(n, [[0, 1], [n-2, n-1], [n-3, n-2], ..., [1, 2]])` which would need `n-3` delayed passes to come to the answer `True`.

All in all, this doesn't sound like \$O(n)\$ worst case, and you need to fix that bug. Either you try something different, or you patch the previous simplification. I’d go with this one and use a `Counter` to track the number of time we delayed the treatment for a given edge. Special care has to be taken to provide hashable objects to the counter:

```
from collections import Counter

def is_valid_tree(n, edges):
    visited_nodes = {0}
    delays = Counter()

    for edge in edges:
        branch = set(edge)
        commons = visited_nodes & branch

        # If a path exist between the nodes in edge
        if commons == branch:
            # A cycle exist and thus it is not a tree
            return False

        # If a node has been visited already
        if commons:
            # Add the branch
            visited_nodes.update(branch)
        else:
            edge = tuple(edge)
            delays[edge] += 1
            if delays[edge] < n:
                # Process later
                edges.append(edge)
            else:
                # Too much delay, can't be processed
                return False

    return n == len(visited_nodes)
```

Comment: re: bugfix, I think you can stop looping if you notice that you've gone through the entire current list of edges without adding anything to `visited_nodes`.  something like `prev_size = -1 ; while len(visited_nodes) > prev_size:  prev_size = len(visited_node) ; for edge  in edges ...`

Comment: Which means that we would need to get `unvisited` back and add `edges[:] = unvisited` after the `for` loop (since `edges.append(...)` would keep the infinite loop). Not really sure it would be more readable. It also has some overhead.

Comment: Or maybe change the loop to be something like: `for edge in set(edges) - visited_nodes: ` ?   Some overhead, but I think it may work out the same as the above code if `n == len(edges)`, which is required for equivalent functionality.

Comment: @pjz Hum... I don't think: `edges` contains couples of nodes whereas `visited_nodes` contains single nodes. But I get your point: we **can** come up with a solution checking for the exact moment when `visited_nodes` stop growing to short-circuit a tiny bit. But it won't magically make the algorithm \$O(n)\$ though.